# DOSCommand (TurboPack) within Console App

Tags: windows, cmd, c++builder

It is possible to use a TurboPack/DOSCommand component within a C++Builder Console application?

**Motivation**. I'm trying to create a console envelope for an old 32-bit MS-DOS console program, that runs in Windows 10 properly. I'm trying to get a call back (`OnNewLine` event) after calling `Execute()` procedure, when the command being executed is an application that requires users' interaction (choosing options like "`(1) for Save`", "`(2) for Calc`", etc.).

I'm trying something like this, but `DOSCommand` does not return anything:

```cpp
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall 
DoNewLine(void *This, System::TObject* ASender, 
const System::UnicodeString ANewLine, TOutputType AOutputType)
{
  if (AOutputType == otEntireLine)
    std::cout << AnsiString(ANewLine).c_str() << std::endl;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
int
_tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    TDosCommand* DosCmd = NULL;
    try
    {
      DosCmd = new TDosCommand(NULL);
      DosCmd->CommandLine = "cmd /c \"dir\"";
      DosCmd->CurrentDir  = "C:\\Windows";

      //Set a new line event.
      TMethod m;
      m.Code = &DoNewLine;
      m.Data = NULL; 
      DosCmd->OnNewLine = reinterpret_cast<TNewLineEvent&>(m);

      DosCmd->Execute();

      //Wait? No response.
      Sleep(10000);

    __finally
    {
      if (DosCmd) delete (DosCmd);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception& E)
  {
    std::cout << "Program terminated due to an exception: ";
    std::cout << E.Message.c_str() << std::endl;
  }
  return (0);
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

When debugging the code, after `DosCmd->Execute()`, `TDosThread.Execute` has not been executed.

**Note:** If I create a VCL Application, with a main form and put a equivalent code inside a TButton's OnClick event, DOSCommand works properly.

I'm using C++Builder Tokyo and Windows 10 (64 bit).

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?  64-bit versions of Windows can't run old MS-DOS applications, and despite it's name DOSCommand can only run MS-DOS commands on 32-bit versions of Windows.

Comment: Hi Ross. I'm trying to create a new envelope for an old 32 bit MS-DOS program that runs in Windows properly. This envelope aims to receive command line parameters and emits them to the old program using SendLine() from DOSCommand.

Comment: 32-bit MS-DOS programs still require a 32-bit version of Windows.  Are you sure it's actually an MS-DOS program and not a Windows console mode program?

Comment: DOSCommand uses internal worker threads that synchronize events to the main UI thread. In order for that sync to work properly in a console app, you have to call [`Classes.CheckSynchronize()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.CheckSynchronize) periodically.  In a GUI app, that is called automatically by the VCL's main message loop. So, in this case, you need to replace `Sleep(10000);` with something more like `#include <Classes.hpp> ... while (some condition is not false) { CheckSynchronize(1000); }`

Comment: Hi Remy. Now it is working properly! I've updated the code with your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved with Remy Lebeau's comment about `CheckSynchronize();`

```cpp
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    void __fastcall
    DoNewLine(void *This, System::TObject* ASender,
    const System::UnicodeString ANewLine, TOutputType AOutputType)
    {
      if (AOutputType == otEntireLine)
        std::cout << AnsiString(ANewLine).c_str() << std::endl;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    int
    _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
      try
      {
        TDosCommand* DosCmd = NULL;
        try
        {
          DosCmd = new TDosCommand(NULL);
          DosCmd->CommandLine = "cmd /c \"dir\"";
          DosCmd->CurrentDir  = "C:\\Windows";
    
          //Set a new line event.
          TMethod m;
          m.Code = &DoNewLine;
          m.Data = NULL;
          DosCmd->OnNewLine = reinterpret_cast<TNewLineEvent&>(m);
    
          DosCmd->Execute();
    
          //Remy's help here.
          while ( DosCmd->IsRunning )
          {
            CheckSynchronize(1000);
          }
    
        __finally
        {
          if (DosCmd) delete (DosCmd);
        }
      }
      catch (Exception& E)
      {
        std::cout << "Program terminated due to an exception: ";
        std::cout << E.Message.c_str() << std::endl;
      }
      return (0);
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
```